# Azure storage file share with AD and MacOS

Tags: azure, mac-osx, network-share, entra-id

My actual simple infrastructure is composed by a VNET with inside these machines:

- Windows Server 2019 that acts as AD controller and DNS server, sync with Azure AD.
- Windows Server 2019 stand alone, not joined to the AD
- A file share storage configured to use the AD for granular permission with a private end point
- Linux box with OpenVPN server

From the AD server I mount the file share and add the right NTFS permission to my users with the granularity I need. From my Windows 2009 stand alone server I can mount my file share using name@domain.com and my password.
In my office I have windows 10 client that once connected to the VPN it can mount easly the share folder, it is not joined to the AD.
With my mac running 11.5.2, connected to the VPN I cannot mount the share using the same credential I used for windows 10 client.
I can ping and resolve the share folder address. If I use the user and KEY I can access it, but I need more granular control.

Comment: It seems is not supported, Active Directory Domain Service authentication for Azure Files is currently only available for Windows clients and not for MacOS clients:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/68803/accessing-azure-file-shares-from-macos.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The transcript of this podcast seems to indicate it is possible: [Episode 175 - File Shares for Clients in the Cloud with Azure Files](https://www.msclouditpropodcast.com/episode175/)